# How to add Onclick method in expandable list view for third level child?

Tags: java, listview, onclick, adapter, expandablelistview

I have implemented three level expandable list view from [here](https://gist.github.com/st-f/2b2a838d3f0258c5c33f).
I just want to go to different activities when I click different childs.

I found that we can implement it in getChildView() methode of SecondLevelAdapter class, but don't know which method to use for handling clicks and how to refer each child uniquely.

I searched lot but couldn't find any answer.

Comment: Have you impplemented the OnClickLister for ListView..?

Comment: no, because for ExpandableListView there is only one methods in docs i.e. ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener, which is for handling clicks on second level items and I want to set for third level items.

Comment: I found that we can implement it in getChildView() methode of SecondLevelAdapter class, but don't know which method to use for handling clicks and how to refer each child uniquely.